# taking a tart out of a glass dish

Tags: serving, tart

I'm looking to make a tart like [this](https://tasty.co/recipe/silkiest-chocolate-tart) or like [this](https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/warm_chocolate_fondant_20828) 
 but I don't have those tart pans that have the removable bottom, I've only got a glass dish.

I'm wanting to take the tart out of the dish and put it on a plate once it's done but I'm not sure how I'll be able to do that. Can I line the glass dish with some baking paper or something so I can pull it out of the dish once it's done, or something?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can line a typical pie pan with parchment paper.

Cut a precise circle to cover the bottom, than a precise rectagle or trapezoid to fit the side. You can use a tiny bit of butter or shortening to stick the parchment paper to the pan and keep it in place.

Once it is cooked, you can work a knife then a spatula or two under the paper and lift it all out in one go.

This is the technique I use making a tartine or even when using a springform pan, because it makes keeping the dish intact relatively much easier.

Comment: If I need to lift something from a pan that doesn't have a loose bottom, I include longer strips of parchment under the layer i put on the base. You can hold the ends of those strips to lift the item clear of the pan, with less risk of damage then using a knife. Of course, with a very fragile tart there would still be a risk to its integrity.